# Can anyone guess what on earth happened to this wall?

Tags: brick, damage

[image: Wall with extensive damage]

Hello, today my wife and I were looking round a lovely 200-year-old house (UK) and one of the outbuildings was in this state. They inform us it's been like this for 20 years, but in my mind, it looks like the bricks are dissolving away.

And clues were to even begin with this?

Comment: Possible moisture/water problems.  The support post looks rusty.  Look for dips in the ground outside where water might collect.

Comment: Appears to be a double wall, with the inner wall (stone blocks? structural tiles?) collapsing and the outer wall (Bricks?) intact.

Answer (score 5):

Where to begin: Assuming you're not so upset about one possibly 200 year old outbuilding with "only good for 180 years" inner wall and end up buying the place...(which I think is what you are implying with "having a look around" but I guess that may not be the case.)

Clear the junk out so you can see, and perhaps someone with experience you hire can see, the full and actual state of the wall. Then do what needs doing it set it right - which might mean *more* tearing down before building back up if the remaining bits are not solid. That, in turn, might require temporary shoring to hold the remainder of the building up until work is completed.

Alternatively, if it's not an outbuilding you need, and not restricted/protected/required to be preserved by local rules regarding elderly buildings, completing the process of having it fall down may be the most cost effective way to deal with it, particularly if experienced inspection reveals that a great deal of expensive work would be required to repair it. You might want to find out if preserving it and restoring it would be required before purchase, in case it's likely to turn into a huge money pit you have no choice about.